# Crystal Report 9 is displaying only the 1st record if records vary only by millisecond

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

I am using SQL Sever 2005, VC 6 ++ and Crsystal Report API to print a report in a child window.

If the records vary **Only** by **Milliseconds**, Crystal Report is showing only the **1st record**. Otherwise, it is perfectly fine.

I am picking the timestamp from SQL Server **DateTime** Field.

In Formula inside Crystal Report, i am only giving the following expression **TableName.TimestampField**.

The Field format for Timestamp field is **mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss**     (in 24 hrs)

**Can you please tell what change i need to make to get all records displayed?**

**Note:-** If I run the same sql query that i give to Crystal Report in Sql Server, It gives me all records.

**New ---- Edited after posting the question.....**

I want to make change in Crystal Report. Actaull, the records inside Cystal Report are being **supprested** based on the following formala:

```
if not PreviousIsNull ({Table.TimeStamp}) then
  if {TABLE.TimeStamp}  = Previous ({TABLE.TimeStamp})
  and  {TABLE.Object_Id}  = Previous ({TABLE.Object_Id}) then
          true
```

Somehow, Cystal Report is comparing Timestamp field only till Seconds.

**Can now you tell me how to force Crystal Report to consider Milliseconds while doing comparison? b/w Timestamps?**

Thanks

Comment: suggest you post the TSQL that drives the report

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005's `DateTime` datatype has a granularity of approximately 3.3 milliseconds.

Comment: That 's right. I found something more, please see the edited question.

Thanks